# GlusterFS Critical Error: Negative fsal_fd_global_counter Freezes NFS Shares - Seeking Root Cause and Resolution

Tags: nfs, glusterfs

I'm encountering a critical issue in my GlusterFS setup that is causing NFS share freezing, leading to significant production downtime. The logs indicate a recurring error message:

```
21/11/2023 16:03:34 : epoch 655c845f : swarm-fs01 : ganesha.nfsd-685[svc_391] remove_fd_lru :FSAL :CRIT :fsal_fd_global_counter is negative: -1
```

This error seems to impact the file descriptor management within the FSAL, resulting in a negative global counter and subsequent freezing of NFS shares. Despite multiple occurrences, I've been unable to isolate the root cause.

The system configuration hasn't undergone recent significant changes, and this issue persists across varying load conditions.

I'd greatly appreciate any insights into the potential origins of this error and any recommended troubleshooting steps or configurations adjustments within GlusterFS to rectify this issue. Additionally, suggestions on how to prevent this from causing NFS share freezes and impacting production would be immensely helpful. Thank you.

Comment: That's an interesting error due to the code is available. For the remove_fd_lru method, the count is decremented before any processing. My guess - could be an edge case like a deadlock, or file descriptor handle that may have been dealt with ungracefully by something other than system. So if that processing does not successfully complete immediately, there is a problem and time for other threads to conflict. Maybe there is a way to enable more verbose logging, not sure. Maybe someone who knows more about NFS. https://github.com/nfs-ganesha/nfs-ganesha/blob/next/src/FSAL/commonlib.c